# How do I import JSON data from S3 using AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue

I have a whole bunch of data in AWS S3 stored in JSON format.  It looks like this:

```
s3://my-bucket/store-1/20190101/sales.json
s3://my-bucket/store-1/20190102/sales.json
s3://my-bucket/store-1/20190103/sales.json
s3://my-bucket/store-1/20190104/sales.json
...
s3://my-bucket/store-2/20190101/sales.json
s3://my-bucket/store-2/20190102/sales.json
s3://my-bucket/store-2/20190103/sales.json
s3://my-bucket/store-2/20190104/sales.json
...
```

It's all the same schema. I want to get all that JSON data into a single database table. I can't find a good tutorial that explains how to set this up.

Ideally, I would also be able to perform small "normalization" transformations on some columns, too.

I assume Glue is the right choice, but I am open to other options!

Answer (score 4):

If you need to process data using Glue and there is no need to have a table registered in Glue Catalog then there is no need to run Glue Crawler. You can setup a job and use [getSourceWithFormat()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext.html#glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext-defs-getSourceWithFormat) with [recurse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-s3) option set to `true` and `paths` pointing to the root folder (in your case it's `["s3://my-bucket/"]` or `["s3://my-bucket/store-1", "s3://my-bucket/store-2", ...]`). In the job you can also apply any required [transformations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/built-in-transforms.html) and then write the result into another [S3 bucket, relational DB or a Glue Catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext.html#glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext-defs-getSink).

Comment: ok, this is interesting, too.  Glue still doesn't make much sense to me and AWS' documentation is atrocious.  have you seen an article that explains how to do what you're suggesting, step by step?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't see any instructions. I was experimenting by my own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Glue is a great tool for this!

Use a crawler to create a table in the glue data catalog (remember to set `Create a single schema for each S3 path` under Grouping behavior for S3 data when creating the crawler)
Read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html)

Then you can use `relationalize` to flatten our your json structure, read more about that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/)

Comment: thanks!  I think this is the right direction, but Glue has still created a new table for every single file, leaving me with thousands of tables.  Do the files need to all have the same names?  (they are actually named like `sales-{timestamp}.json` so they are all unique.

Comment: No, the file names can be unique. Have you checked the `Create a single schema for each S3 path` box under crawler info?

Comment: yes, i did as you suggested and still got thousands of tables.  that's further than i had gotten before, but something still doesn't seem right.

Comment: What is your include path? Have you set it to:  s3://my-bucket

Comment: yes, that's exactly what it's set to.  I actually just gave up and decided not to use Glue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Json and AWS Glue may not be the best match. Since AWS Glue is based on hadoop, it inherits hadoop's "one-row-per-newline" restriction, so even if your data is in json, it has to be formatted with one json object per line [[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/hive-json-serde.html)]. Since you'll be pre-processing your data anyway to get it into this line-separated format, it may be easier to use csv instead of json.

*Edit 2022-11-29*: There does appear to be some tooling now for [jsonl](https://jsonlines.org/), which is the actual format that AWS expects, making this less of an automatic win for csv. I would say if your data is already in json format, it's probably smarter to convert it to jsonl than to convert to csv.